# How to swap id segment position in C# MVC routes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

The usual route is like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I want to have the id specified before the action so I wrote these 2 routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Most of the requests work except for the following case:

```
Foo/2
```

The Index action is not called.
How can I get to the expected behavior?

Comment: You need to supply a route constraint (e.g `id = "^\d+$"`). The routing handler thinks it's an action.

Comment: Well the action match should be done in the first rule and if it fails it should pick the second one (with the Index action if it's not specified). I'll try your method.

Comment: I'm saying it's looking for a `2` action on the `Foo` controller. I would also reverse the order those routes are defined (since MVC goes with the first match). Rule of thumb is most specific to broadest when defining.

Comment: This is the reason why routes are defined in the order they are, because the optional portions should come at the end... not in the middle.  It's very hard to differentiate optional routes this way.  In your case, it can work with a route constraint on an integer.. but if your middle parameter were a string there would be no way to known the difference between the first and second routes...

Comment: I can confirm it works with the constraint and swapping the routes. Thank you, maybe you can make it an answer so I can accept it. I was expecting the matching algorithm to try the first route and then jump to the second and solve the default parameters. @ErikFunkenbusch My order would accept a string id but would not put in the default value for the action.

Comment: @user2704 - no, it wouldn't.  It would treat a string id as an action.  It couldn't tell the difference between `/home/{id}` (where id is a string) and `/home/{action}`, therefore it would treat your string id as an action and you would get a 404 error.  ie, if your url were /home/mystringid it would try to find an action name mystringid on your home controller, and give a 404 when it couldn't find it.

Comment: You're right, I conducted more tests. Thank you.